# How to generate custom primary key with timestamp in mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, primary-key

In MariDB I want to create a table for invoice with an auto generated id that consist of 'YYYY' concatenated with 'select count('id') from where company_id = 'id'. The id is of type varchar. Normally I use a simple id like `id integer auto_incremented primary key`. This time I want to customize my id in a different way.

The result should be something like this:
`20210001`
I was thinking doing something like the following:

```sql
table create invoice (
id varchar(10) primary key date('YYYY').(select count('id')+1 where company_id = xxx)
...
)
```

I don't know if that's the right thing to do or there's a better approach. How can I achieve an auto generated invoice id based on year and total invoices + 1?

The reason for this is, I want a table of invoices with unique ids like: 2021-company_id-sequential_nr_per_company
that can be directly used as invoice id. Instead of using an integer as primary key I was thinking of a unique string of characters as primary key which is also an id that will be printed in the invoice document. If I make it too complex, I'd like to see a better and simpler way.

Comment: Imagine that a row was deleted - next insertion will cause PK value duplication in this situation.

Comment: Good point, although rows in this table shouldn't be deleted, but it's a good thing to think about it. It can be solved by using MAX().

Comment: What you propose here is very difficult and expensive to do reliably and scalably without running the risk of race conditions. Using `SELECT 1 + MAX(id)` to help make a PK is notorious for causing PK collisions when databases are under heavy production load, but not during testing. The workarounds can wreck INSERT performance.  If you *must* do this, please [edit] your question to explain a bit about *why*. That way we can give you specific advice.

Comment: And if you ever go with a clustering topology, you will find auto_increment jumping by 3.

Comment: Do not use `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Consider using a MariaDB `sequence`.